# Keep the default axis values but just turn them to percentages

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I'm wondering how I can *keep the default y-axis values by R* in my plot but just turn them to percentages? Specifically, if we need to use `axis()` how should we specify "`at =`" in `axis()` to keep the default tickmarked values?

An example is here:

```
x = rbinom(10, 100, .7)
plot(x)
```

Here is what I thought might work but didn't:

```
plot(x, yaxt = "n")
tk = par("yaxp")
axis(2, at = seq(tk[1], tk[2], l = tk[3]), labels = paste0(seq(tk[1], tk[2], l = tk[3]), "%"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job for you:

```
plot(x, yaxt="n")
   axis(2, at=axTicks(2), labels=paste0("%", axTicks(2)))
```

Below, you can see the result of `plot(x)` and solution above side by side:

```
   set.seed(123)
   x = rbinom(10, 100, .7)

   plot(x)

   plot(x, yaxt="n")
   axis(2, at=axTicks(2), labels=paste0("%", axTicks(2)))
```

[image]
[image]